# Is there a way to insert "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in a datetime database field?

Tags: 7, datetime

Is there a way to insert "0000-00-00 00:00:00" datetime database field?
Should I change the database field's default value to "0000-00-00 00:00:00"?

I got replies on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499808/insert-0000-00-00-000000-to-datetime-in-mysql-database), and it works with plain PHP, but it gives an error with Drupal.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please tell us how you defined database column you want to insert data to, what PHP code you are trying to execute (and how you injected it to Drupal), and what error do you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 DB API, support for the `datetime` type was [removed](https://drupal.org/node/159605). This means that you must use use `mysql_type` or `pgsql_type` if you want this functionality.  Below is an example of of to declare this schema provided your database is MySQL.  By setting `not null` to `FALSE`, you can store an empty value (`''`), which is equivelent to `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`:

```
'mydate_date' => array(
  'description' => t('My date field.'),
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => FALSE,
),
```

Note that to make the schema portable, you should provide a fallback type (`varchar`) for the case that the database is *not* mySQL.